# Concerning the standard decomposition of $S^3$

Tags: algebraic-topology

On page 47 of A. Hatcher's alg top book, the author explains that

> Notice that meridional circles in $S^1\times S^1$ bound disks in the first solid torus, while it is longitudinal circles that bound disks in the second solid torus.

(The context is the decomposition of $S^3$ into $S^1\times D^2$ and $D^2\times S^1$)

Could someone give a rigorous explanation of the second sentence please?

I'm unhappy in particular about the following point: Which of these disks (bounded by the longitudinal circles) contain the compactification point?

I'll be grateful for a response.